# How to find transitive dependencies in an Android project

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, libraries

I have the problem. I have undesired dependency, that is not included explicitly in the gradle file. I cannot figure out how to find which dependency transitively includes this one.

How can I find out where does this dependency come from ?

I have tried

```
gradlew analyze
```

But fails to compile my project

Thanks

Comment: Or run `./gradlew app:dependencies`, as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/65876235/7365866

Answer (score 7):

`dependencyInsight` task can do this for you. Example:

```
 gradle -q lib:dependencyInsight --dependency groovy --configuration compile
```

or for Android

```
gradlew -q app:dependencyInsight --dependency gson --configuration debugCompileClasspath
```

Will show why dependency containing `groovy` in its name is included in `compile` configuration of the `lib` project. See this [doc section](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html#sec:dependency_insight) for details

Comment: With gradle 3.0 we have to use construction like this: **gradlew -q app:dependencyInsight --dependency gson --configuration debugCompileClasspath**

Comment: To find out configurations in your project, run `./gradlew app:androidDependencies`. There all configurations are listed for the `app` module. Although default, `debugCompileClasspath` not always is a configuration in the `app` module (neither is the `app` module always called `app`).