# Gradle get a list of all dependencies

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I am writing a task for ProGuard and I need to get all the dependencies that are in the project, and then iterate over them. I mean, I need to get subproject dependencies, all transition dependencies, and so on.

As a result, I have to copy all the compileOnly dependencies, at which I need to exclude the dependencies that are already in the compile in transitive dependencies

Simply put, I need an array that will contain something like this class. How i can get it ?

```java
interface Dependency{
    String getArtifact();
    String getGroup();
    String getVersion();
    Scope getScope();
    File getJarFile();
}
```

Comment: Can't you just use the proguard task on your module jar file, then add the dependencies with the shadow jar plugin?

Comment: @tim_yates, im need get libs for proguard

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html Try this link

Answer (score 4):

If you want to see all dependencies in your project you can use this command line in the Android Studio terminal:

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

You will be able to see something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

buildSrc

```
import org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolvedArtifact;

public class DepName {
    public String id;
    public String scope;
    public String group;
    public String artifact;
    public String version;
    public String jarFile;
    public ResolvedArtifact resolvedArtifact;

    public DepName(ResolvedArtifact resolvedArtifact) {
        this.resolvedArtifact = resolvedArtifact;
        this.id = extractId(resolvedArtifact);
        String[] ids = this.id.split(":");
        this.group = ids[0];
        this.artifact = ids[1];
        this.version = ids[2];
        this.scope = "compileOnly";
        this.jarFile = resolvedArtifact.getFile().getAbsolutePath();
    }

    private String extractId(ResolvedArtifact resolvedArtifact) {
        String displayName = resolvedArtifact.getId().getDisplayName();
        return displayName.substring(displayName.indexOf("(")+1, displayName.length() -2);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DepName{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", sc='" + scope + '\'' +
                ", g='" + group + '\'' +
                ", a='" + artifact + '\'' +
                ", v='" + version + '\'' +
                ", f='" + jarFile + '\'' +
                ", ra=" + resolvedArtifact +
                '}';
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
def depNames = new ArrayList<DepName>()
allprojects {
    afterEvaluate {
        configurations.compileOnly.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.each {d ->
            depNames.add(new DepName(d))
        }
    }
}

task compileOnlyList {
    doLast {
        println("The compileOnlyList \n ---------")
        println(depNames)
    }
```

Sample output

```
The compileOnlyList 
 ---------
[DepName{id=':my-jms:1.', sc='compileOnly', g='', a='my-jms', v='1.', f='/Users/projects/lib/my-jms-1.2.jar', ra=my-jms-1.2.jar (:my-jms:1.2)}]
```

Comment: How to call task compileOnlyList  without doLast() ? If im use doLast in proguard task, im get
Execution failed for task ':proguard'.
> Index: 0, Size: 0